# using st.deferred() to generate dictionary values using hypothesis with known keys, and specific value strategies doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, testing, pytest, hypothesis-test, python-hypothesis

I'm trying to generate complex tree like dictionaries for testing my code.
the dictionaries are basically compound classes, that contains list of structs and more simpler fields.

I'm using hypothesis strategies deferred method, with a lambda function implementation, I want to map a certain generated 'key' to a specific strategy made for that 'key'. for some reason it's looks like my mapping doesn't work as expected and different 'keys' are getting different strategies.

would appreciate your assistance. thanks.

This is what I've tried:

```
name_strategy = st.text(min_size=0, max_size=10)
fanout_ref_strategy = st.lists(st.booleans())

MyClass_keys = [
    "name",
    "fanout_ref",
]  

MyClass_strategy_mapping = {
    "name": name_strategy,
    "fanout_ref": fanout_ref_strategy,
}
MyClass_value_strategy = st.deferred(lambda: MyClass_key_strategy.map(MyClass_strategy_mapping.get) | MyClass_key_strategy)
MyClass_key_strategy = st.sampled_from(MyClass_keys)
MyClass_strategy = st.dictionaries(keys=MyClass_key_strategy, values=MyClass_value_strategy)

@given(specific_dict=MyClass_strategy)
def test_specific_dictionary(specific_dict):
    # Your test code here
    print(specific_dict)
```

This is the generated output I see:

```
{}
{}
{'name': text(max_size=10)}
{'fanout_ref': 'name', 'name': text(max_size=10)}
{'fanout_ref': text(max_size=10), 'name': text(max_size=10)}
{'fanout_ref': lists(booleans())}
{'fanout_ref': lists(booleans()), 'name': lists(booleans())}
{'fanout_ref': text(max_size=10), 'name': lists(booleans())}
{'name': lists(booleans()), 'fanout_ref': lists(booleans())}
{'name': lists(booleans()), 'fanout_ref': 'fanout_ref'}
{'name': text(max_size=10)}
{'name': text(max_size=10)}
```

I Was expecting to have dictionaries, with 'name' and 'fanout_ref' as keys, and strings and lists of boolean as values.

Answer (score 0):

[The idiomatic way to do this uses `st.fixed_dictionaries()`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.fixed_dictionaries):

```
MyClass_strategy = st.fixed_dictionaries(
    {"name": st.text(min_size=0, max_size=10),
     "fanout_ref": st.lists(st.booleans())}
)
```

---

Separately, you might want to understand why your example code doesn't work.

One bug is that the `keys=` and `values=` strategies for `st.dictionaries()` are *completely independent* - if you need specific values per key, you'll need to use `fixed_dictionaries()`, or generate and merge a dictionary for each group of keys that share a values strategy.

Another bug is that in `st.deferred(lambda: MyClass_key_strategy.map(MyClass_strategy_mapping.get) | MyClass_key_strategy)`

- the `st.deferred()` isn't doing anything
- the `| MyClass_key_strategy` says that you can generate values from the keys strategy
- the `.map()` returns the strategy as a value; to *also* draw from the returned strategy you need `.flatmap()`.  [Here's the docs](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#chaining-strategies-together); it'd look like `= MyClass_key_strategy.flatmap(MyClass_strategy_mapping.get)`.

Finally, `st.dictionaries()` doesn't always generate all possible keys - you'd need to set `min_size=2` for this, although it's a really bad way to generate from a fixed set of keys relative to `fixed_dictionaries`.